# How to compile and flash attiny88 with arduino-cli?

Tags: arduino, attiny, arduino-cli

I can't understand, what device-name I should use for attiny88? For example, string for my old nano was **arduino:avr:nano:cpu=atmega328old**

I installed cores for attiny in arduino-cli, and test this board in ArduinoIDE and it works well, but I want to use arduino-cli.

(Sorry for my English)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, this string named as FQBN. And I can get this FQBN for all my boards after exec command `arduino-cli board listall`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).